# QGIS measurement tool seems unrealistic

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, measurements, ellipsoid

I have created a buffer of 150m around a point. This should give (a polygonal approximation of) a circle with radius 150m.

I tried to verify this with the measurement tool, and I am baffled to see a difference of ~30% in length, depending on whether I choose the "Cartesian" or the "ellipsoidal" measurement. The first one gives the expected 150m, the second one only gives 103m.

I think:

- The difference between Cartesian and ellipsoidal measurements can never be this big on such a short distance.
- Ellipsoidal distance should always be greater than Cartesian distance.

My layer CRS is "EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator".

Am I thinking wrong, or is this some error in QGIS?

Screenhsots of the measurements (sorry - only in German):

[image: cartesian measurement]

[image: ellipsoidal measuremnet]

Comment: Never ever try to measure distances and areas using Web Mercator, because of the effect you're observing. Choose a different, local, m-based CRS and try again.

Comment: OK, good to know. Do you know the reason why? Which of the measurements is correct?

Comment: Web Mercator is ***never*** correct on distance.

Comment: Consider an equal area projection for your analysis. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209019/what-is-the-ideal-equal-area-projection-to-map-germany-switzerland-and-austria